# SQL query find records that not persists in other tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, qsqlquery

I need to print all persons which are **not** students and not teachers. I have three tables. Oracle database. Code so far:

```
SELECT PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DateOfBirth
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON PERSON.PersonID = S.StudentID 
INNER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PersonID = T.TeacherID
WHERE PERSON.PersonID != S.StudentID
AND PERSON.PersonID != T.TeacherID;
```

I guess my query is wrong because it returns 0 results. Do you have any idea what must I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " my query is wrong because it returns 0 results"

Inner joins return records when there is a match. You're trying to find PERSON records which join to neither STUDENT nor TEACHER. So, change your query to use outer joins:

```
SELECT PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DateOfBirth
FROM PERSON 
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT S ON PERSON.PersonID = S.StudentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PersonID = T.TeacherID
WHERE S.StudentID is null
AND  T.TeacherID is null;
```

This is an anti-join: it returns records from PERSON which don't match records in STUDENT and TEACHER.

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from person p
where not exists (select 1 from teacher t where t.teacherid = p.personid) and
      not exists (select 1 from students s where s.studentid = p.personid);
```

Although you can write this query with `left join`, I think the version using `not exists` is almost a direct translation of the question, making it easier to understand.

In Oracle, you can also write this using `minus` -- if you want only the id:

```
select personid
from person
minus
select teacherid
from teacher
minus
select studentid
from student;
```

Comment: What 1 stands for?

Comment: @TeodorKolev . . . `exists` and `not exists` only check that a *row* is returned, not the contents of the columns.  `1` is the simplest way to define a column.

Comment: I give both answers upvote, but @APC answer seems more proper (with one select)

Answer (score 0):

--Try this with Left Outer Join...

```
SELECT
  P.PersonID, 
  P.FirstName, 
  P.LastName, 
  P.Gender, 
  P.DateOfBirth
FROM PERSON P
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT S ON P.PersonID = S.StudentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEACHER T ON P.PersonID = T.TeacherID
WHERE S.PersonID is null and T.PersonID is null
```

Comment: This seems remarkably similar to my answer which I posted half an hour ago, and which the OP has accepted as correct.

Comment: Haha I am first timer in stack overflow...I was having trouble formatting it correctly.

Comment: Well now you know how to format an answer you can learn how to delete one :)  Seriously, there are plenty of questions which don't have any answers, why not tackle some of them? Duplicate answers just clutter the thread and less useful as a resource for future Seekers.